# How do I create a lock/unlock button and behavior in my secure preference pane?

Tags: cocoa, security, macos, authentication

Is there a guide out there for imitating the Lock/Unlock button and behavior of the secure Apple preference panes? (e.g. Network)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want an [SFAuthorizationView](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Security/Reference/SecurityInterfaceFramework/Classes/SFAuthorizationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You also want to study the [Authorization Services Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts).

Comment: That is indeed exactly what I want. I knew there had to be a way to do it without creating it from scratch. Thanks.